# Copy files from azure blob storage to local storage in pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy test.xml from azure blob storage to c:\data\test.xml in local computer in azure devops pipeline. I want to do this as pipeline task, So I am assuming running a powershell script with PAT token passed. as per different articles, I can use [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10). But I want to avoid this installation and can simply copying file.

Comment: If you want to use AZCOPY,  installation is needed. Consider using rest api. E.g. [Get Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve like this using azure cli task.

```
          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: 'Download Keys From Blob'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx'
              scriptType: 'ps'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: 'az storage blob download --file "test.xml" --name "test.xml" --container keys --connection-string "$(ConnectionStringInetpubKeys)"'
              workingDirectory: 'C:\inetpub\keys'
```